# Energy in the body

Tags: energy

Theoretically if you can increase the electrical charge in your body, making your body a battery that could produce constant energy could you increase the capacity at which the rate we move and or even think?

Considering your body physiological uses electrical signals to communicate with the brain and to the rest of the body, what happens if you increase the charge to a tolerable amount?

Answer (score 1):

Not as much as you think.  The reason is that electrical charge isn't what you think it is.  When we think of electricity, including the electricity in our neurons, we're thinking of flowing electricity from high potentials to low potentials.  If we merely increase the electric charge (slowly), the result is static electricity which, without flowing, doesn't do what you expect.

[image: Van de graffe]

That's probably about 100,000 volts of static electricity in that picture.  100,000 volts of *flowing* electricity would kill you instantly.  Static electricity will not.

As for trying to pump someone up with electricity to make them think faster, that's simply not how it works.  Biology.SE could give you more, but simply putting more juice in the body won't cut it.